# argparse.ArgumentParser ArgumentError when adding arguments in multiple modules

Tags: python, argparse

I am working on automated test framework (using pytest) to test multiple flavors of an application. The test framework should be able to parse common   (to all flavors) command line args and args specific to a flavor.
Here is how the code looks like:

parent.py:

```
import argparse
ARGS = None
PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()
PARSER.add_argument('--arg1', default='arg1', type=str, help='test arg1')
PARSER.add_argument('--arg2', default='arg2', type=str, help='test arg2')

def get_args():
    global ARGS
    if not ARGS:
        ARGS = PARSER.parse_args()
    return ARGS
```

MainScript.py:

```
import pytest
from parent import PARSER

ARGS = None
PARSER.conflict_handler = "resolve"
PARSER.add_argument('--arg3', default='arg3', type=str)


def get_args():
    global ARGS
    if not ARGS:
        ARGS = PARSER.parse_args()
    return ARGS

get_args()


def main():
    pytest.main(['./Test_Cases.py', '-v'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Test_Cases.py

```
from MainScript import get_args

ARGS = get_args()


def test_case_one():
    pass
```

Executing MainScript.py fails with following error:

E   ArgumentError: argument --arg3: conflicting option string(s): --arg3

Comment: No repro. `MainScript.py` executes just fine. Also, `TestCase.py` is never used. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Where's your `mywork` module defined? Is `main` ever called in `MainScript.py`?

Comment: Sorry. Modified the code. @Aran-Fey it should execute now.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that you have declared

```
PARSER.add_argument('--arg3', default='arg3', type=str)
```

in a global scope inside `MainScript.py`. That means that that line of code will be executed every time you import it like you do in `Test_Cases.py` hence why you get the conflict error, you're adding arg 3 to your argparse twice.

Easiest solution is to move `PARSER.add_argument('--arg3', default='arg3', type=str)` into your `main()` function as that will only get called once.

```
def main():
    PARSER.add_argument('--arg3', default='arg3', type=str)
    pytest.main(['./Test_Cases.py', '-v'])
```

But doing that causes another problem stemming from your multiple definition of `get_args()`. When you call `get_args()` before your `main()` it only has the two defined arguments from `parent.py` so it's missing arg3. If you move the call down into your `main()` or at least after your `main()` gets called it will work.

Personally I just removed both the definition and the call of `get_args()` from `MainScript.py` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Right. But shouldn't following code resolve the conflict?
    PARSER.conflict_handler = "resolve"

Comment: @piyush Not in the way you declared it. You need to set the `conflict_handler` in the constructor: `PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(conflict_handler='resolve')` before it starts to play nicely. But regardless, why would you chose to force a conflict to be resolved instead of avoiding the conflict in the first place? Will it work? Sure. But I feel like it'll bite you later on in your development.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as I had defined one  of the argument twice.